# How to insert page break in creation of PDF File using saved .png files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, pdf-generation

I am creating pdf File using the screen shots taking programatically from webView.

But main problem is that below code does not insert page break its only creating whole page.

Please tell me how to insert pageBreak or create multiple page in pdf.

```
- (void) drawPdf
{
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, webViewHeight);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    //UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    double currentHeight = 0.0;

    for (int index = 1; index <= imageName ; index++)
    {

        NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
        UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

        [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];        
        currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;

    }
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void) drawPdf
{
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, webViewHeight);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);


    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    //UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    double currentHeight = 0.0;

    for (int index = 1; index <= imageName ; index++)
    {
      UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);
     //Above line would work to make page break

        NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
        UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

        [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];        
        currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;

    }
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```